# ImageView: How to draw a grey circle in front of a icon?

Tags: android, android-imageview

As you can see on the screenshots, I have a icon [image: current] on the left side of this.

**How can I draw a grey circle on the front of that left icon in the layout xml, as in following screenshot?**

Screenshot [image]

Comment: in the screenshot I see a circle under the X cross, but, you want a selector? something that appear when the click is done? or the standard X cross should have the circle behind it all the time?

Comment: @xanexpt No, the grey circle shall be just drawn, no touch events etc.

Comment: ok, i will put as awnser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#BCBCBC" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:drawable="@drawable/your_cross_icon">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#BCBCBC" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
            <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp"></size>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp" android:gravity="center" android:drawable="@drawable/cross">
    </item>
</layer-list> solved my issue, thnx

Answer (score 1):

create this drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#666"/>
</shape>
```

then put it as background of the image view, and put the X as the src of imageview

The circle is the drawable that is behind the image.

This way you can reutilize the drawable and put in several icons

Comment: Yes that worked! Can I modify the diameter of this shape? Scale?

Comment: yes, you can put the with and height inside the shape, or you can change the size in imageview directly

Comment: @RalfWickum I dont understand, if you said it work, why do you accept the other guy answer...

Comment: I can set the radius there. Thnx

Comment: lol, ok... i understand :P you dont know that you can set the radius in both options... you can put the radius in more places too (as I said in the previous comment)